# Possible to add "conflicting" Drivers to Windows 7 Installer?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, windows-installer, oem

Is it possible (and smart) to include all bunch of diffrent drivers to a Windows 7 installer so Windows could theoretically install all needed drivers during the Windows installation?
Meaning can I add drivers to my Windows OEM Installer (not a system image that only properly works on the same computer) without having Windows load them on every boot up and just having them available in case Windows gets installed on the hardware the driver is actually used for.

For example, I would add the latest Realtek LAN and Intel LAN driver to the installer. Would that conflict in any way or make the installed system unstable because Windows would load both drivers (no idea if it does that, thats my question) on boot even if one of them isn't actually used? Also would Windows even use these added drivers over compatible default Windows drivers?

My goal is it to make the Image as universal as possible with none or only very little driver installation after the computer got setup.
I would need to add a lot of drivers from diffrent chipsets but I'm worried that Windows isn't smart enough to choose the correct drivers and everything gets messed up by having all these drivers on the system.

Comment: Generally referred to as "slipstreaming"/"slipstream" drivers into the Windows install images.